# Maven GWT (SmartGWT): How to organize my project to prevent long compilation

Tags: gwt, maven, compilation, smartgwt

Dear StackOverflow Users,

I want to split my huge application written in SmartGWT, compiled by maven, into several subprojects, for example: common, custom-widgets, forms, custom-datasources, sites.

The main idea is: once subproject is compilated by GWT can be easy used in other sub-project to skip compilation again. (sorry for my english, but I think You got my point)

example subproject `pom.xml` is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>eu.nanobeauty</groupId>
        <artifactId>nanobeauty</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>common</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>nanoBeauty :: Common</name>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${gwt.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

`Common.gwt.xml` is :

```
<module>
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.User"/>
    <inherits name="com.smartgwt.SmartGwtNoTheme"/>
    <source path="common"/>
</module>
```

and the parent `pom.xml` is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>eu.nanobeauty</groupId>
    <artifactId>nanobeauty</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>nanoBeauty :: Parent</name>

    <modules>
        <module>datasources</module>
        <!-- multimodule : each form different project -->
        <module>forms</module>
        <!-- multimodule : each site different project -->
        <module>sites</module>
        <module>common</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <gwt.version>2.5.0</gwt.version>
        <smartgwt.version>3.1</smartgwt.version>
        <java.version>1.6</java.version>
        <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</webappDirectory>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.war.plugin.version>2.1.1</maven.war.plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>smartclient</id>
            <url>http://smartclient.com/maven2</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.smartgwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>smartgwt</artifactId>
            <version>${smartgwt.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${gwt.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
            <version>${gwt.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

After long night googling i found solution:

It cannot be done this way I want to achieve.

GWT needs source files to generate JS files. Main module `pom.xml` is ok and example `.gwt.xml` file above is also ok. Only change is in sub-module `pom.xml` files only goal is `resources`.

So for every submodule I need to setup `pom.xml` that looks like similar to:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>eu.nanobeauty</groupId>
        <artifactId>nanobeauty</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>common</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>nanoBeauty :: Common</name>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${gwt.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Based on this documents:

- [Resources goal](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/resources-mojo.html)
- [Multimodule project](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/project.html#Multi-project_setup)